# How do I add/combine a list and a integer together into a list (Python)?

Tags: python

I am trying to add the list in the if statement with the number in the elif statement. How do I add them together to get the resulting output?

```
def sorting(tup1, tup2):
    output = []
    sumVal = 0
    wholeTup = tup1 + tup2 
    for i in range(0, len(wholeTup)):
      if i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
        word = wholeTup[i].title()
        output.append(word)
        output.sort()     
      elif i % 2 != 0:
        sumVal = sumVal + wholeTup[i] 
    return output

print(sorting(("Bob",21,"kelly",21), ("morgan",10,"Anna",2)))
```

The output should look something like:

```
["Anna", "Bob", "Kelly", "Morgan", 54]
```

Their names in alphabetical order and all of their ages added together.

I know the if statement will give me this portion of the output:

```
["Anna", "Bob", "Kelly", "Morgan"]
```

And the elif statement will give this portion:

```
54
```

How can I combine those two together? Is it even possible to combine the output of the if statement and the elif statement?

Comment: So you want to sort the names in the tuples that are on *even* indices and sum up the ages?

Comment: It would actually help if you explained exactly what the criteria is for the output? Having to guess and figuring out by running your code and troubleshooting is not very fun.

Comment: Just what is wrong with the code you show?

Comment: How can I combine the output of the if statement and elif statement? @RoryDaulton

Comment: Yes @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the line:

```
output.append(sumVal)
```

to the program just before the `return` statement to add the total sum of the odd parts of the tuples, like:

```
def sorting(tup1, tup2):
    output = []
    sumVal = 0
    wholeTup = tup1 + tup2 
    for i in range(0, len(wholeTup)):
        result = " "
        if i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
            word = wholeTup[i].title()
            output.append(word)
            output.sort()     
        elif i % 2 != 0:
            sumVal = sumVal + wholeTup[i]
    output.append(sumVal) # append the total age to the final result
    return output
```

Nevertheless your code is rather *unelegant*, *un-Pythonic* and inefficient*. A few ideas:

- you sort the list all the time, whereas sorting it as post-processing step is more efficient;
- you can simplify the `if`; and
- there is no need to check with an `elif`, a simple `else` would suffice since the condition in the `elif` is the exact opposite of the condition in the `if` statement.

You can transform the entire program into two statements with *generators*:

```
def sorting(tup1, tup2):
    wholeTup = tup1 + tup2 
    return sorted(wholeTup[i] for i in range(0,len(wholeTup),2)) + \
        [sum(wholeTup[i] for i in range(1,len(wholeTup),2))]
```

Here `sorted(..)` will catch all the elements of the *generator* `wholeTup[i] for i in range(0,len(wholeTup),2)` and construct a `list` with the elements sorted. Here the generator will emit all the elements that are positioned at even places.

Furthermore `sum(..)` on the other hand will sum up the elements yielded by the generator `wholeTup[i] for i in range(1,len(wholeTup),2)` and generate the sum of the ages (elements positioned at the odd places). We construct a singleton-list `[..]` with that result and *append* it to the result of the `sorted(..)` call. This is the final result we `return`.

Comment: What if there was a None instead of an integer for one of the person's name?

Comment: @aj2929: both programs will error. What should happen in that case?

Comment: Would a try / except work in this case? Like try this.. except TypeError, do this instead @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @aj2929: how can you know that without **defining the expected behavior** first. In order to solve a problem: you first have to define all corner- and edge cases. Then you can think on **how** to implement it. It is like asking whether "A hammer will work?" without knowing what task you aim to solve.